# Access "SeparatorView" from UITableViewCell.subviews Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to remove all the `subview` from my `UITableViewCell` but keep `SeparatorView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

In Objective-C, we can do:

```
for (UIView *subview in cell.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasSuffix:@"SeparatorView"]) {
        //Do something here
    } else {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

But when I try to do the same in Swift:

```
cell.subviews.forEach({
    if !NSStringFromClass($0.class).hasSuffix("SeparatorView"){
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }
})
```

`$0.class` is invalid

I need to remove all the subview when I reload the `UITableView` in order to prevent adding two same subviews.

Could you help to figure out how do write this part of code?

Comment: Why are you trying to remove all subviews from the cell? Keep in mind that if you are adding your own subviews to the cell and you wish to remove those, be sure you only add (and remove) them to the cell's `contentView` and not directly to the cell itself.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you, I never thought about it :) and it works so good

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent swift code. I'm not familiar with $0.

```
for subview in cell.subviews {
        if !NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder).hasSuffix("SeparatorView") {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

But as Maddy suggested in comments, add subviews to cell's contentview and remove from cell's contentview.